# Add "Duplicate Record " to either the input title field or input name field - depending on if either exist, otherwise find the first text field

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, selector, var

I need this function to look at input text fields to discover if the field input **input[name='xxxx']** is name='title', or name='name', else find the first text field type=text, and add a new value 'Duplicate Record ' to the existing field found. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
// Add "Duplicate Record " to either the input title field or input name field - depending on if either exist, otherwise find the first text field.
  var $e = $(this);
    if ( $e.is("input[name='title']") ) {
            var selector = "input[name='title']";
      }
    else if ( $e.is("input[name='name']") ) {
            var selector = "input[name='name']";
      }
    else {
            var selector = "input[type=text]:first";
      }

  var oldValue = $(selector).val();
  var newValue = "<?php echo escapeJs(t('Duplicate Record ')); ?>" + oldValue;
  $(selector).val(newValue);
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I need the if and else if statements to look at the **input[name='xxxx']** of a field to determine if the **XXXX** is labeled 'title' or 'name' and apply the corresponding if statement **var selector** else look for the first **var selector = "input[type=text]:first";**